# SAML Logout Request to ADFS through HTTP-Redirect Binding getting response as requestor not a success -Request initiated from browser

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, adfs

the following one is my SAML assertion from ADFS

```
<samlp:Response ID="_69ecb15f-97ad-4d68-b69e-8eb30a37af8e" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-09-21T16:19:29.472Z" Destination="https://localhost:4200/auth/login" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="ml101e1a-1d87-18dc-1b33-198e1d2a1459"
    xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
    <Issuer
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://saml.mlads.mi***ic.app/adfs/services/trust
    </Issuer>
    <samlp:Status>
        <samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Success" />
    </samlp:Status>
    <Assertion ID="_acced75d-5742-49ee-ad54-4f72049d3268" IssueInstant="2021-09-21T16:19:29.471Z" Version="2.0"
        xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">
        <Issuer>http://saml.mlads.m**ic.app/adfs/services/trust</Issuer>
        <Subject>
            <NameID>Administrator@mlads.m**.app</NameID>
            <SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer">
                <SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="ml101e1a-1d87-18dc-1b33-198e1d2a1459" NotOnOrAfter="2021-09-21T16:24:29.472Z" Recipient="https://localhost:4200/auth/login" />
            </SubjectConfirmation>
        </Subject>
        <Conditions NotBefore="2021-09-21T16:19:29.468Z" NotOnOrAfter="2021-09-21T17:19:29.468Z">
            <AudienceRestriction>
                <Audience>https://localhost:4200</Audience>
            </AudienceRestriction>
        </Conditions>
        <AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2021-09-21T16:19:29.404Z" SessionIndex="_acced75d-5742-49ee-ad54-4f72049d3268">
            <AuthnContext>
                <AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport</AuthnContextClassRef>
            </AuthnContext>
        </AuthnStatement>
    </Assertion>
</samlp:Response>
```

And my sso logout request

```
<samlp:LogoutRequest ID="_a78ea30f-b1a7-40fc-9a64-a41196d95582"
                     Version="2.0"
                     IssueInstant="'''+ datetime.now(pytz.utc).strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ')+'''"
                     Destination="https://saml.mlads.mindlogic.app/adfs/ls/"
                     xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol">
  <Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">https://localhost:4200</Issuer>
  <NameID xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">Administrator@mlads.m**.app</NameID>
  <samlp:SessionIndex>_12c18cfe-6f98-4322-bdd3-a5685dca9399</samlp:SessionIndex>
</samlp:LogoutRequest>
```

BUT I AM getting below logout response

```
<samlp:LogoutResponse ID="_1ff3c824-2e33-4f29-b3d7-a6d52e8d9e41" Version="2.0" IssueInstant="2021-09-21T16:36:28.994Z" Destination="https://localhost:4200/auth/login" Consent="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:consent:unspecified" InResponseTo="_a78ea30f-b1a7-40fc-9a64-a41196d95582" xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol"><Issuer xmlns="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion">http://saml.mlads.***.app/adfs/services/trust</Issuer><samlp:Status><samlp:StatusCode Value="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:status:Requester" /></samlp:Status></samlp:LogoutResponse>
```

My following adfs configuration rule

E-mail address -> NameID
but  i am always getting "requestor" response instead of "success"

Comment: Have you URL encoded the SAMLRequest as well?. You should encode all three parameters

Comment: yes i did and updated in my question too.@AkshayGaonkar

Comment: The logout request is missing entity id.  `<samlp:LogoutRequest ID="">`. Also there is a slight difference in `NameID` format when compared to your ADFS response and logout request. Check the hyphen missing in ADFS response. `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameidformat:emailAddress` and `urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress`. Both the format should exactly match

Comment: its issue in the destination it should adfs/ls now i can able to logout but i am getting response as "Requestor" instead of success  I updated my saml assertion and logout request and logout resoponse @AkshayGaonkar

Comment: For signout there must be two correct identifications: NameID and SessionIndex. In your case the session index is different

Answer (score 0):

some points to notice

1. Saml logout request must contain some important parameters like Identity provider(ID), issuer.And this Id in the logout request must match the InResponseTo parameter in the logout response.
2. The NameID, including format, must exactly match the NameID of the assertion.

   ```html
       <samlp:LogoutRequest xmlns:samlp="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol" 
       xmlns:saml="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" 
       ID="ONELOGIN_********** "
       Version="2.0" IssueInstant=" "
      Destination="https://*******/adfs/services/trust">
      <saml:Issuer>https://localhost:4200</saml:Issuer>
              //
           //
       </samlp:LogoutRequest>
   ```

3.Check if the SAML request deflate (compression)and encoding is properly done.

Comment: I have update my assertion and logout request and response @kavyasaraboju-MT

Answer (score 0):

though the session index and nameid are the same as long as we tried to initiate from the browser it's not working but if the same request is working when we triggered from the registered application I don't know why if someone explains it would be good.

Comment: Please edit this information into the question, or even as a comment on your question. On this site, we reserve Answers strictly proposed solutions.